# Excel spreadsheet formula to sum a column

Tags: worksheet-function, spreadsheet

I'm trying to create a formula that sums a total of only the trailers that are in the yard, but don't have a Date Unloaded next to them.

[image: spreadsheet]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: You already know countif, try `countifs`!

Comment: Is there a way to get the formula to single out lines that don't have a certain column filled with data?

Comment: So countifs will add all of the blank rows in a single column?

Comment: I'm sorry, i think the formula i need is one to add blank cells to get a total number.

Comment: I have one last comment, Just need another formula to reflect the cells that are due, but don't have a cell that says yard yet.

Comment: Advanced Filters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=COUNTIFS(D2:D100,"=YARD",F2:F100,"=")
```

Replace the `100`s with whatever your max row number is, or use the select tool.