# Count based on multiple alternate conditions in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, cells

I need a formula to count any trailers that are due in but do not have a cell that says "yard" or have a date next to that trailer. Please see screenshot. I tried the COUNTIFS formula and was unsuccessful.[image: trailer log spreadsheet]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excel spreadsheet formula to sum a column](http://superuser.com/questions/939015/excel-spreadsheet-formula-to-sum-a-column)

Comment: This is a duplicate, but my question was never answered and i tried to explain my issue a little bit better in this one. Can someone please help?

Comment: Can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong if COUNTIFS is the correct formula to use?

Comment: What is your countifs formula?

Comment: =COUNTIFS(C53:C3000, "=DUE", F53:F3000, "=")

Comment: I also tried this formula: =COUNTIFS(C52:C3000, "=DUE" , D52:D3000 "=" ) and i have no luck. I'm not very sure how it works.

Comment: Your description is ambiguous.  It could describe any of the following logic: OR(AND(Due, not Yard),Date) vs. OR(AND(Due, not Yard),not Date) vs. AND(Due,OR(not Yard,Date)) vs. AND(Due,OR(not Yard,not Date)).  Please clarify.

Comment: I need to make the spreadsheet reflect trailers due only without a yard or date cell.

Answer (score 1):

You can add as many conditions as you need. You can do

```
=COUNTIFS(C1:C3000, "=DUE", F1:F3000, "=",D1:D3000,"<>Yard")
```

Or

```
=COUNTIFS(C1:C3000, "=DUE", F1:F3000, "=",D1:D3000,"=")
```

Note that I started the rage from row 1 because the range in your screenshot is till row 52 not from 52 as in your note.

Comment: Joshua, was this a satisfied answer? If yes, please mark as accepted. Otherwise, please edit your question to describe what’s not working.